# Handlebar incrementing variable

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I'm new to Javascript templating

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div  class="inner_recipe_box {{index}}">
        <div class="recipe_box_img">
            <a data-ref='Retailbox'  href='{{plink}}' title='{{ptitle}}'></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I am seeking to add an incrementing class to inner_recipe_box like box1 box2 box3 I am not sure how can I accomplish this without converting into each if I need to use each here what changes would I need to make to my code , I tried using {{index}} and {{@index}} but in vain

Comment: Are you doing this inside an `{{#each ...}}` block? `{{@index}}` only works inside `{{#each ...}}`. Also, what does this have to do with jQuery? Maybe there's some code you forgot to include?

Comment: No i am not using each , I am just using the script tags

Comment: Please show us all of your code. We can't help you if we don't know how this is being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of using `index` is `{{@index}}` and it only works inside `{{#each ...}}` blocks.

You should create something like:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   {{#each elements}}
        <div  class="inner_recipe_box{{@index}}">
            <div class="recipe_box_img">
                <a data-ref='Retailbox'  href='{{plink}}' title='{{ptitle}}'></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Where `elements` has the following structure:

```
elements = [{
    plink: '/some/url/123',
    ptitle: 'The title'
},{
    plink: '/other/url/123',
    ptitle: 'Great Gatsby'
},{
    plink: '/cool/url',
    ptitle: 'Sherlock'
}, ...]
```

**Note:** If you wish to have `inner_recipe_box1` `inner_recipe_box2` etc. you should not put a space between `box` and `{`.

Right: `inner_recipe_box{{@index}}` Wrong: `inner_recipe_box {{@index}}`.